# Help with user interface translation

Tags: i18n-l10n

Our portals are using User Interface Translation to do the translations. These copies/texts are located in the front-end as part of the content, or sometimes are pop ups.

This tool is not translating. That has to be done manually and the tool only provides a box where to input the translation.

Questions:

1. Does Drupal allow to automatically translate interface strings by just selecting the desired target language?
2. Is it possible to mass-upload translations in Drupal? How would we achieve it?

[image: User interface]

Comment: Have a look into the translation management module (https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt). It can use external services (e.g. Google Translate API) for translation jobs. And - configured properly - may come close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This tool used to be called "Translate interface" in Drupal 7, and it seems they should have stuck to the name.

1. No, this tool doesn't actually translate the interface, it only stores the translations you enter there yourself, it allows you to search through existing strings and enter new translations.

   As suggested in the comment you may find outside services that do translations for you.
2. This tool has Export and Import options (you can see them as tabs in your screenshot), you can use them to export into the usual .pot file format (common in translating) and use an application to translate through there, then import the edited file into Drupal.

   There are tools you can use to convert the .pot files into CSV for example, although it's better to keep to the standards. [PO and POT files](https://www.drupal.org/node/1814954)

**Drupal Localization project** is where anyone can contribute translations for Drupal core and contributed projects. You can do your translations there and let the whole community benefit: [Translate to Thai](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/th/translate)

If you have any custom modules on your site you'll have to translate yourself through that tool, Export/Import or some third party service as mentioned.